# update ever row with max and min marks

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with subject and with marks. every subject has max and min marks, i need to update rows with their max and min marks for ever subject

| subject | Marks |
| --- | --- |
| Maths | 95 |
| Eng | 85 |
| Maths | 90 |
| Eng | 56 |

I need output table like below, whenever particular maths subject comes max should be 95 and min should be 90, same for eng subject as well

| subject | Marks | maxmarks | minmarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Maths | 95 | 95 | 90 |
| Eng | 85 | 85 | 56 |
| Maths | 90 | 95 | 90 |
| Eng | 56 | 85 | 56 |

Comment: Show us your current query attempt!

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On older versions of MySQL, we can join to a subquery which finds the min/max mark values for each subject:

```sql
SELECT t1.subject, t1.Marks, t2.maxmarks, t2.minmarks
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT subject, MIN(Marks) AS minmarks, MAX(Marks) AS maxmarks
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY subject
) t2
    ON t2.subject = t1.subject;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(marks) over (partition by subject) as max_marks,
       min(marks) over (partition by subject) as min_marks
from t;
```